# Determining stack size in iterative depth first search (DFS) algorithm

Tags: c++, stack, iteration, size, depth-first-search

I have written an iterative implementation of depth first search (DFS) algorithm in C++. It produces correct visiting order as output. Algorithm goes like that:

1. Initiate visited[] array with false values.
2. Push first vertex into stack.
3. Pop element from stack and assign it to variable v.
4. If v was not visited (visited[v] == false), print v and set it as visited.
5. Push every not visited neighbors of v into stack (biggest value first).
6. Repeat 3-5 until stack is empty.

The problem I have is to determine proper Stack s size in DFSIteratively method of GraphUtilities class. My teacher stated it has to be stored as array. I am able to calculate it's size using (n * n - 3 * n + 2) / 2 equation, where n is vertex set count, assuming no visited vertex is ever pushed into stack and full graph was provided (most dense graph; pessimistic case).

Can stack size be determined for factual graph, which most likely will not be a full graph? Or, better yet, is there a way to push every vertex into stack only once? I know recursive implementations solves this limitation, as well as using dynamic data struct as stack, but my project assumes using array (educational purposes, that's what I was told).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class Stack
{
private:
    int ptr;
    T *stackArray;
    int stackSize;

public:
    Stack(int n)
    {
        ptr = -1;
        stackSize = n;
        stackArray = new T[stackSize];
    }

    ~Stack()
    {
        delete[] stackArray;
    }

    void push(T x)
    {
        if(ptr + 1 == stackSize)
            throw length_error("Cannot push.");

        stackArray[++ptr] = x;
    }

    T top()
    {
        if(ptr == -1)
            throw length_error("Cannot pop.");

        return stackArray[ptr];
    }

    T pop()
    {
        T temp = top();
        ptr--;

        return temp;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if(ptr == -1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};

class Graph
{
private:
    int numberOfVertices;
    list<int> *adjacencyList;

public:
    Graph(int n)
    {
        numberOfVertices = n;
        adjacencyList = new list<int>[numberOfVertices];
    }

    int getNumberOfVertices()
    {
        return numberOfVertices;
    }

    list<int>* getAdjacencyList(int v)
    {
        return &adjacencyList[v];
    }

    list<int>* getAdjacencyList()
    {
        return adjacencyList;
    }

    ~Graph()
    {
        delete[] adjacencyList;
    }

    void addEdge(int v1, int v2)
    {
        adjacencyList[v1].push_back(v2);
    }
};

class GraphUtilities
{
private:
    bool *visited;
    stringstream visitingOrder;

public:
    void DFSIteratively(Graph &g, int v)
    {

        int n = g.getNumberOfVertices();
        list<int> *adjacencyList = g.getAdjacencyList();
        visited = new bool[n];
        Stack<int> *s;

        // Determine size of stack.
        if(n == 1)
            s = new Stack<int>(1);
        else
            s = new Stack<int>( (n*n - 3*n + 2)/2 );

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            visited[i] = false;

        s -> push(v);

        while(!(s -> isEmpty()))
        {
            v = s -> pop();

            if(!visited[v])
            {
                visitingOrder << v << " ";
                visited[v] = true;

                for(list<int>::reverse_iterator i = adjacencyList[v].rbegin(); i != adjacencyList[v].rend(); ++i)
                    if(!(visited[*i]))
                        s -> push(*i);
            }
        }
        cout << visitingOrder.str() << endl;

        visitingOrder.clear();
        delete[] visited;
        delete s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Graph graph(6);
    GraphUtilities utilities;

    graph.addEdge(0, 1);
    graph.addEdge(0, 2);
    graph.addEdge(0, 4);
    graph.addEdge(1, 0);
    graph.addEdge(1, 5);
    graph.addEdge(2, 0);
    graph.addEdge(2, 5);
    graph.addEdge(3, 5);
    graph.addEdge(4, 0);
    graph.addEdge(5, 1);
    graph.addEdge(5, 2);
    graph.addEdge(5, 3);

    utilities.DFSIteratively(graph, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

My graph (paint quality): http://i.imgur.com/pkGKNFo.jpg

Output:

> 4 0 1 3 5 2

Comment: Isn't this more of math question than a programming question? Have you tried http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It might be. Thanks, I will certainly check it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might be happier if you'll use additional `addedToStack` flag array of size `n` next to your `visited` array. So if you'll add a vertex to stack it will not be visited but added to stack.  There is no need in adding it to the stack again. Check **addedToStack** flag each time you want to add a vertex to the stack. Eventually every vertex will occur in the stack not more than once and the stack size will be **n** at most.